# Определить с какой стороны сталкивается объект

Tags: c#, unity3d

У меня на сцене есть куб и сфера как сделать чтобы при столкновении сферы с кубом определять в какую сторону куба  врезалась сфера.

Comment: Вы имеете ввиду определить какая из граней куба касается со сферой в момент столкновения или что?

Comment: да именно то что вы написали!

Comment: А как заданы ваши фигуры? (не знаком с unity и другими 3d-движками)

Comment: Поставьте коллайдеры со всех сторон где может касаться сфера, повесьте на них IsTrigger, и в коде куба проверяйте какого коллайдера коснулась сфера. Сейчас напишу ответ.

Comment: а сцена в каком измерении? 2д или 3д

Comment: У меня 3D сцена___

Comment: Можно момент столкновения вычислять координаты объектов, по которым и определять с какой стороны произошло столкновение.

Comment: А это дело_______

Comment: @ГеннадийП, легко придумать пример, который сломает эту логику

Comment: @Aqua, 5 коллайдеров на объект - это сильно конечно :)

Comment: @RiotBr3aker я не так прочитал вопрос я вместо куба прочитал квадрат, и с квадратом было бы нормально вроде... Я просто кинул идею никто не отвечал и я предложил

Comment: @RiotBr3aker Для примитивов это более чем достаточно. Конечно, для более сложных фигур нужно использовать другую логику.

Comment: @ГеннадийП для сферы и куба, как это и указано в вопросе, можно придумать пример, который сломает ваше решение. Было бы 2 куба - ещё можно понять, и то с натяжкой.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Самый простой способ - создать N-ное количество коллайдеров и проверять каждый из них.

Если же этот путь не подходит, то тебе нужно игратся с Raycastом. и смотреть в сторону point of impact. Дальше смотреть с какой именно стороны импакт был относительно пивот поинта и реагировать уже в зависимости от этого. Слева -- левая сторона. Справа -- правая и т.д.

Детали для помощи реализации сможешь найти здесь:
https://answers.unity.com/questions/785746/anyway-to-tell-which-side-of-a-collider-is-hit.html

гугл подсказал что делать в первой ссылке по запросу: "unity collider check side"